# Oracle read and return data from cursor

Tags: oracle, sys-refcursor, oracle19c

I'm trying to create a stored procedure in Oracle that has one input parameter and one output variable and, in case of results, return a dataset to my .Net Application. The main issue is that I can't change the signature of the procedure and need to do if condition to validate if exist records or not.
The main issue that i've being struggled is with cursors (to execute and return the information), and to count the results of the select.

Here is an example of what i'm doing to try to retrieve the data.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Testing (v_input IN VARCHAR2(50), v_OutID NUMBER(1))
AS

   TYPE v_record_botoes IS RECORD (
        v_dummy_col1 VARCHAR2(50),
        v_dummy_col2 VARCHAR2(250)
    );
   TYPE table_botoes IS TABLE OF v_record_botoes;
   tt_botoes table_botoes;

   v_ref_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;

   CURSOR v_cursor IS
     (SELECT dt.v_dummy_col1,
           dt.v_dummy_col2
    FROM dummy_table dt
         WHERE v_dummy_col3 = v_input);

   v_check NUMBER;

BEGIN
   tt_botoes := table_botoes();
   v_check := 0;

   FOR v_row IN v_cursor
   LOOP
      tt_botoes.extend;
      tt_botoes(tt_botoes.COUNT) := v_row;
   END LOOP;

   v_check := tt_botoes.COUNT;

   -- condition that need to know the nr of records of the select
   IF v_check = 0 THEN

      v_OutID := 0;

   ELSE

      v_OutID := 1;

      OPEN v_ref_cursor FOR
      SELECT *
         FROM tt_botoes; -- also tryed "FROM TABLE (tt_botoes)" and "FROM TABLE (cast(tt_botoes AS table_botoes))"

      -- return dataset to .net application
      DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_ref_cursor)

   END IF;

END;
```

Already tryed to convert the *v_cursor* into a *sys_refcursor* to be outputed by the *DBMS_SQL package* but didn't get anywhere.
Also i've tried to create a temporary table to hold the information, but then have a concurrency issue.

Any idea what i'm doing wrong, or any other possible solution to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Completely untested because I do not have the environment to test it but I would structure this quite differently, see below (I am assuming that the missing out in the specification is just a typo)

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_Testing (v_input IN VARCHAR2(50), v_OutID **out** NUMBER(1))
AS

   v_ref_cursor SYS_REFCURSOR;
   v_check NUMBER;

BEGIN

   select count(1) 
   into v_check
   from dummy_table dt 
   WHERE v_dummy_col3 = v_input


   -- condition that need to know the nr of records of the select
   IF v_check = 0 THEN
      v_OutID := 0;
   ELSE
      v_OutID := 1;

      OPEN v_ref_cursor FOR
      SELECT dt.v_dummy_col1,
             dt.v_dummy_col2
      FROM dummy_table dt
      WHERE v_dummy_col3 = v_input

      -- return dataset to .net application
      DBMS_SQL.RETURN_RESULT(v_ref_cursor)
   END IF;
END;
```